# how can I create two files with same name with different case in mac osx

Tags: files, osx

I can't create two files with same name with different cases in a folder.
as an example if file names are like below.

`test.java` and `Test.java`.

warning message appear that saying

```
The name “Test” with extension “.java” is already taken. Please choose a different name.
```

in Linux we can do this. how can I do this in mac osx?

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71357/how-to-check-if-my-hd-is-case-sensitive-or-not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You generally can't. Mac OS X is typically case-insensitive.

It's actually a per-partition setting, AFAIK set when formatting the partition. The default is case-insensitive, and case-sensitive is known for breaking third-party apps. If you decide you need it, I suggest creating a case-sensitive disk image to store those files.

(You might also like to know about another site in the Stack Exchange network, [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)—presuming you haven't already heard of them.)

Comment: I have used the HFS+ case sensitive for some 13 years and UFS before that and never had either file system "break things". Some third party GUI applications  will not install because they refuse to re-write their applications to run on HFS+ case sensitive.

Comment: @fd0 That's what I meant by break things. If you're mostly using Unix utilities in Terminal, it'll be fine. If you want to use an Adobe product, good luck. (Not to mention, creating a disk image is much easier than reformatting a partition, if that's required!—at least a partition with data on it)

Comment: Given that Mac OS claims to be POSIX compliant, it would of course need to be fully functional with a case sensitive filesystem.

Comment: @fd0  I've updated the answer to say its known for breaking third-party apps, does that sound better?

Comment: @schily same thing about that update

Comment: Well, this is different from Microsoft where switching NTFS case sensitive (e.g. for SFU) causes Microsofts compiler to stop working as file names used in the compiler supplied include files are a random mix of upper and lowercase letters ;-)

Comment: @schily no, you just have to worry about Apple forgetting to quote the paths they're passing to `rm -Rf` (which I remembered being a mistake they made in the XCode installer, but Google only found them doing it in iTunes).

Comment: Are you talking about spaces in filenames?

Comment: @schily That's what I remember (and what I found via Google about iTunes). But it's a complete tangent here... We should take it to [chat] if we want to continue.

Comment: Well, I would word it differently as "some third party application will not install or run properly on HFSX". For the record, I have Adobe Lightroom installed on HFSX and use it regularly without any issues. Now that I think of it, even Apple has pushed out an update that is not compatible with HFSX, their notorious flashupdater.